# Selecting columns associated with a header on a dataTable

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I have been asked to highlight the columns associated to a certain `<th>` whenever the user clicks on that `<th>`. All of this in a **PrimeFaces** `<p:dataTable>`

The easiest way I could think of was to do it with `JQuery` so I started to research, and stumbled upon this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759676/1316000).

There, **BalusC** presented a piece of code that I was able to edit for my own use case, and I ended up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mainForm\\:table th').click(function () {

        var th = $(this);
        var index = $('th', th.parents('tr')).index(th);
        var column = $('tbody td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')', th.parents('table'));
        column.addClass('light-grey');
    });
});
```

This code actually works for me. But there's one thing I can't figure out.

As soon as the `light-grey` class is added to the columns, it is removed. I don't know if it has to do with JSF's lifecycle or something about rendering time that I do not know about.

So the result I get is that the columns *blink* to grey and back really fast.

Does anyone know why this happens?

---

**EDIT 1**

Here is my `xhtml`:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{myManagedBean.items}" var="item"
        sortBy="#{item.value2}">

        <p:column headerText="Value 1" sortBy="#{item.value1}">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.value1}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Value 2" sortBy="#{item.value2}">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.value2}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Value 3" sortBy="#{item.value3}">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.value3}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I created a small project to isolate the problem, and the table above is the one I'm using for tests.

And yes, an AJAX request is fired whenever I click on the headers to alter the sorting. I checked in the Network tab of Chrome's debugger.

Comment: After you click it and it blinks, does it still have a class of `light-grey`?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock Nope, the class isn't there anymore. I've check it with Google Chrome's debugger

Comment: Can you paste the xhtml file? Did you check if it's being re-rendered via AJAX? You can see that in the inspector console, if there's any AJAX call when the header is clicked.

Comment: @MaQy , I added the code you requested, check the 1st edit

Answer (score 0):

With **@MaQy's** comment I was able to come up with a solution, the final `JQuery` code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function afterLoad(){
        var th = $('.ui-datatable table th.ui-state-active');
        var index = $('th', th.parents('tr')).index(th);
        var column = $('tbody td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')', th.parents('.ui-datatable'));
        column.addClass('light-grey');
    }

    $('body').bind('ajaxComplete', function(e, xhr, settings){
        afterLoad();
    });

    // Invoking afterLoad() for the first time 
    // to load the table already highlighted.
    afterLoad();
});
```

`ui-state-active` is a class that PrimeFaces adds to the selected `<th>`, so that made things a little easier.

If you guys have any suggestions, improvements or complaints about this solution, please comment. In my little knowledge of JQuery this was all that I could come up with.